# Ubuntu One - Files API - Cloud - More detailed info somehwere?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, cloud

I am just starting on a mobile app for Ubuntu One, and I'm reviewing the info at
https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/cloud

I find the information a bit lacking though. It's a nice reference, but for someone not familiar with it, I had to goggle search to find out what a "volume" was exactly (its kind of obvious, but never hurts to know the specifics)

There's also things like:

> GET /api/file_storage/v1/volumes
>
> Return a JSON list of Volume Representations, one for each volume. A volume is a synced folder, or the Ubuntu One folder, owned by the user. Note that all volume paths begin with ~.:

... but there's no such thing as a JSON "list". Does it mean array ?

And other things... So I was wondering if here existed another page with more detailed information. Maybe some sample request / responses or something? I could just write a little proof of concept app to answer some of these questions... but I prefer not to unless I have to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't yet another page, although I'm working on it. (And yes, a JSON array.)

I'd be happy to chat over this stuff with you; it would be useful to me to get your feedback on what you'd like to see in the documentation (sample request/response pairs is a good idea), and hopefully useful to you as well. There are various example apps around; if you're developing on Ubuntu, you may find u1oauthrequest, in the ubuntuone-couch package, useful for testing: `u1oauthrequest https://one.ubuntu.com/api/file_storage/v1/~/Ubuntu%20One` will be the node for your Ubuntu One folder, for example. [u1fn9](http://kryogenix.org/code/u1fn9/) shows accessing the file storage API from JavaScript in a QML app; the source for the U1 Android and iOS apps is open and on Launchpad; [u1ftp](http://kryogenix.org/days/2012/09/11/accessing-ubuntu-one-file-storage-via-ftp-from-any-os) is a Python example of accessing the files API.

Comment: Thanks or your response. I am developing in j2me. 
Some sample request/response pairs would be great, yes. Another thing that would be nice to see is some member/value types. Mostly it is string, but sometimes I'm not sure. For example the "generation" value. Is it it sufficient to treat it as a int?, as a long? maybe even double? (json int/fraction/exponent) What format are the dates ("when_created") etc...

Comment: I was able to answer some of these questions for myself by reverse engineering the sample apps. Seeing what method calls they were doing using whatever JSON library was linked.

As I said, its a good reference, and it has all the information strictly "needed". Just having some of this other info, would certainly save some time, or help reduce any potential confusion.

Comment: Cool; I'll look into some sample exchanges and data types. You may also find https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/files/store_files/android useful if you don't already know about it; it's a J2SE library, but it may work on j2me as well, or at least help you get started.

Comment: Hi again, I have a last question for you for. In J2ME there is no support for "PUT". Do the Ubuntu One web servers support some kind of POST with ?method=put appended to the URI?

Just to save time making my own socket connections.

Comment: I am trying to upload a file. I just tried every variation I could think of but I guess its not going to work, since apparently POST is not even accepted. Keep getting 405 :(

Comment: A 405 is METHOD NOT ALLOWED, suggesting that you're POSTing to the wrong URL. (We don't support a faked PUT, I'm afraid.) Do the above alternatives work (u1ftp, u1oauthrequest, and so on) -- that will help you diagnose whether you're using the correct URLs (and will help me update the docs if you discover what you're doing wrong)? You could track me down on IRC (aquarius on freenode) and we can chat over the code, if that would help?

Comment: All the URL I've used for authentication, fetching volumes and directories, and downloading files has worked so far. For downloading files I changed to use https://files.one.ubuntu.com/ { content_path }

All of these require http GET, but the problem I am having now is with uploading files. So I am using that same https://files.one.ubuntu.com/, but unfortunately PUT is not supported in J2ME. So instead I am trying now to use a secure socket, and I just learned that s40 platform doesn't support that either. My lucky day :D

Comment: I think it can be done, just not using standard SecureConnection interface, so I'll keep playing around with it and see what happens. If I'm still having trouble after I can make a socket connection, ill look you up to discuss, but I'm fairly certain the URI is ok.